# How do you use pipenv in a GitHub action?

Tags: python, docker, github-actions, pipenv

I'm using pipenv to install python dependencies for a GitHub action. This is what my pipfile looks like:

```
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]
pylint = "*"

[packages]
pandas = "*"
pygithub = "*"
matplotlib = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

This is what the Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3

COPY main.py /
COPY Pipfile /
COPY Pipfile.lock /
COPY views.csv /

# https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4273
RUN pip install 'pipenv==2018.11.26'
RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile

ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "run", "python", "./main.py"
```

I can run the docker image locally on my machine and everything works as expected, but when I push it to GitHub, it fails with:

```
Virtualenv location: /github/home/.local/share/virtualenvs/workspace-0SZQOxG8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from github import Github
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'github'
```

For some reason, when the docker image is run on the GitHub vm, it's not picking up any of the dependencies.

**Edit 7/28/2020:**

This is the main.yml for the workflow that triggers the action.

```
on: 
  push: 
    branches: 
      - master


# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "insights_job"
  insights_job:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: GitHub insights 
      id: insights
      uses: ./
```

Comment: How exactly did you create/configure the GitHub action?

Comment: I have an action.yml and Dockerfile in the root of the repo. I added a workflow (which I added to the original question) which triggers the action when changes are pushed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short version

Just add this to the top of the Dockerfile:

```
# Tells pipenv to create virtualenvs in /root rather than $HOME/.local/share.
# We do this because GitHub modifies the HOME variable between `docker build` and
# `docker run`
ENV WORKON_HOME /root

# Tells pipenv to use this specific Pipfile rather than the Pipfile in the 
# current working directory (the working directory changes between `docker build` 
# and `docker run`, this ensures we always use the same Pipfile)
ENV PIPENV_PIPFILE /Pipfile
```

## Long version

As can be seen [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/using-environment-variables#default-environment-variables), Github actions defines the `HOME` environment variable to be `/github/home`.

We can see that this variable is then passed to to the docker container via the `run` command that is visible in the action's step's logs:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name c201c6ad6ba986775dbb96d3c072d294f3c8_a057c6 --label 87c201 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/j/j":"/github/workspace" 87c201:c6ad6ba986775dbb96d3c072d294f3c8
```

(Notice the `-e home` flag)

`pipenv install` creates a virtualenv in `$HOME/.local/share/virtualenvs` and installs all the dependencies in that directory. `pipenv run ...` then uses that same path find the virtualenv to run the required command.

During the build stage of the Docker image (`docker build`), `$HOME` has the default value of `/root` (because that's the root user's home directory), so virtualenv gets created in `/root/.local/share/virtualenvs`.

However, during the `docker run` stage, `HOME` is set to `/github/home` (as described above). Thus, the virtualenv gets created in `/github/home/.local/share/virtualenvs`.

To summarize -

`pipenv install` uses `/root/.local/share/virtualenvs`

`pipenv run` uses `/github/home/.local/share/virtualenvs`

That means the dependencies are installed in one placed but expected to be in a different place when the script is actually ran.

To overcome this, we can use set the `WORKON_HOME` in the Dockerfile using an `ENV` statement.

The `WORKON_HOME` variable is respected by `pipenv` and it will prefer to place its virtual environments in the path defined in `WORKON_HOME` rather than the path defined in `HOME`.

So the solution would be to add

`ENV WORKON_HOME /root`

To the `Dockerfile`.

However, this is not enough, since pipenv chooses the virtualenv according to the location of the `pipenv` file. The `--workdir` is set to `/github/workspace` by Github and then the entire project source code is mounted into that folder, so when we `pipenv run` we're actually using the `Pipenv` file in `/github/workspace`. This is a different `Pipenv` file than the one that was copied during the `docker build` stage into `/` and that was used for the `pipenv install`. Since two different Pipenv locations are used, two different virtualenvs will be used.

To solve that we can use the `PIPENV_PIPEFILE` environment variable. This variable tells `pipenv` to look for the `Pipfile` in the location specified by that variable instead of in the current working directory.

Let's also add this to our Dockerfile:

```
ENV PIPENV_PIPFILE /Pipfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation, that fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much @omer-tuchfeld It resolved my issue.